# How can I authenticate SharePoint REST calls from Android App?

Tags: android, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a website that is built using SharePoint Foundation 2013.I have a number of list and libraries there.

For Example:
I need to develop a android application to show the SharePoint List Items/Data.
Using the SharePoint 2013 Rest API, We can get the Data form SharePoint.

But The problem is the authentication. I'm using Windows NTLM claim based authentication in the SharePoint foundation 2013.

How can I authenticate my SharePoint site inside the android application and get the SharePoint data and displays it in the android app?

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use NTLM Authentication library on Android.

Check out this:
http://danhounshell.com/blog/android-using-ntlm-authentication-with-httpclient/

You can use the JAR available at this location to make HTTP requests with NTLM:

http://jcifs.samba.org/

Answer (score 0):

We use 3rd party library [JShare](http://www.independentsoft.com/jshare). This library supports NTLM and works with Java and Android